# Correct Site for a historical fiction question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

What is correct Stack Exchange site for a question about historical fiction?

Here is the context:

Many years ago I read a rather interesting book that tracked the life of two physical objects (a whip and a crown perhaps) over several centuries. The book was given to me as a child by my father, who read it as a child. Napoleon's invasion of Russia plays a role in the book with two characters surviving a winter using the remains of a horse for shelter. I am now trying to find the name of the book and if it is still in print.

Comment: See also https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/3607/139

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identify fictional book/story: where to ask?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284383/identify-fictional-book-story-where-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, there isn't a Stack Exchange for this.  There was a Literature.SE, which might have been the place for this question, but that site was shutdown after a failed beta.  There's an attempt to resurrect it over on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80865/literature), which I recommend you contribute to if you're interested in Q&A on books and literature in general.

Comment: The proposal was deleted, but https://literature.stackexchange.com/ is alive and kicking ([since 2017-01-18](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/1/is-there-anything-that-definitely-confirms-that-svidrigailov-actually-committed))