# Identify fictional book/story: where to ask?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Science Fiction and Fantasy has a highly active [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) tag but where should I ask for identification of fictional stories that are of neither science-fiction nor fantasy genre?

Comment: Related: [Correct Site for a historical fiction question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251676/21960)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps the [proposed Literature site](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93238/literature) will allow general story-identification requests.

If your story belongs to that domain, [Mythology](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/) allows for identification requests. Apart from that, I do not think there is any existing site that would suit your needs.

Comment: Literature is even in commitment stage now.

Answer (score 2):

The [**Literature Stack Exchange**](https://literature.stackexchange.com/) proposal mentioned in Wrzlprmft's answer has been in public beta since early 2017 and does indeed accept story identification questions. These questions should be tagged [`identification-request`](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) and must fulfil a number of criteria, which are described in the tag wiki:

> A list of details one should consider adding to their question includes, but is not limited to:
>
> - **When did you read the story, and how old was it?**
>
>   Did you read it 10 years ago? Last summer? "When I was in high school" is not descriptive. Try to provide a year range instead.  Was it an old crumbling book or a fresh one? Did you see it in a magazine from the 1980s or on a website yesterday?
> - **Medium and appearance**
>
>   What did the cover look like? Was it a thick book? A magazine? Short story collection? Novel? Maybe printed in a textbook? Was it an online story?
> - **What language did you read it in, and was it translated?**
>
>   What language did you read the book in? This helps to narrow down the possibilities. In case you read a translation, you should also try to provide the *original* language the book was written in - this will significantly narrow down the search area.
> - **Where did you read this story?**
>
>   Public library? Airport book shop? USA? Italy? Any of these will help.
> - **Anything else**
>
>   Every little detail will help - do not omit anything just because you think it is insignificant. Even details that you are unsure of can be included, just with a disclaimer that you are unsure about them.